# When using History.pushstate how do I prevent the URL from getting longer each time I click on a link?

Tags: javascript

I'm using pushstate from the HTML 5 History API to change the URL in my single page application.

```
history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, 'home/index/' + documentTitle);
```

I want to prepend the "home/index/" each time when changing the URL so that it looks like this:

```
mysite.com/home/index/documentTitle1

mysite.com/home/index/documentTitle2

mysite.com/home/index/documentTitle3

mysite.com/home/index/documentTitle4
```

But what happens is this instead:

```
mysite.com/home/index/documentTitle1

mysite.com/home/index/home/index/documentTitle2

mysite.com/home/index/home/index/home/index/documentTitle3

mysite.com/home/index/home/index/home/index/home/index/documentTitle4
```

And so on I think you get the point. How can I prevent that from happening? I thought the URL manipulation from `history.pushstate` just adds the URL to the current URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use absoulte Urls. With
`history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, '/home/index/' + documentTitle);`
you directly overwrite the url from its root (-> '/')

If your program runs on a subdirectory, you have to prefix this. meaning:

```
var baseUrl = "/app1";
history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, baseUrl + '/home/index/' + documentTitle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using an *absolute* URL instead:

```
history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, 'http://example.com/home/index/' + documentTitle);
```

or starting the URL with a `/`:

```
history.pushState(stateObj, nodeName, '/home/index/' + documentTitle);
```

From the docs for `pushState`:

> The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL